# Is there a way to rotate column's to row in snowflake?

Tags: multiple-columns, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot

I have table with single row like below which comes from snowflake query like below

```
show warehouses like 'COMMON_WH';
select "name","state","type","size" FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))

name|state|type|size
COMMON_WH|SUSPENDED|STANDARD|Small
```

I Want to rotate it like below.

```
name| COMMON_WH
state|SUSPENDED
type|STANDARD
size|Small
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [unpivot](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html). Here is an example of how to use it. Note that it is a bit verbose because you need to cast all of the original table's datatypes to the same datatype before the unpivot (`varchar` in this case).

```sql
show warehouses like 'COMMON_WH';

select *
from (
    select
        "name"::varchar  as name,
        "state"::varchar as state,
        "type"::varchar  as type,
        "size"::varchar  as size
    FROM TABLE (RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
) unpivot (col_val for col_name in (name, state, type, size))
```

**This produces:**

| COL_NAME | COL_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| NAME | COMMON_WH |
| STATE | STARTED |
| TYPE | STANDARD |
| SIZE | X-Small |

Comment: HI Simon, I have updated the question to be more precise what i exactly want to do in snowflake.  The answer you replied may not work as I rely here on the result set from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID().

Comment: Answer is been updated again based on your new requirements